# ;[magento] "all categories" block magento

Tags: magento, templates, block, categories

[image]

Where can I find this file to replace "all categories" to ALL or delete header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find text in translation files at app/locale/_your-language-theme/Mage_Catalog.csv OR you can create new translation for your template moving this file to your app/design/frontend/..../.../locale/.../Mage_Catalog.csv